# "undefined reference to" in MakeFile

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I'm a noob to MakeFile. I have read all similar posts on stackoverflow. But still don't know how to do (I'm sure this is a MakeFile problem because I can run it with XCode). Here are my MakeFile and Error msg:

```
####### Detect system architecture

SYSARCH       = i386
ifeq ($(shell uname -m),x86_64)
SYSARCH       = x86_64
endif

####### Compiler, tools and options

CXX           = g++
LINK          = g++
MAKE          = make
DELETEFILE    = rm -f
DELETEDIR     = rm -Rf
DEFINES       = -DQT_WEBKIT -DGL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
COMMONFLAGS   = -Wall -Wextra -pipe -msse2 -Wno-reorder 
#-Werror 
####### Detect debug or release

DEBUG         ?= 0
CXXFLAGS          ?=
ifeq ($(DEBUG), 1)
    CXXFLAGS      += $(COMMONFLAGS) -DDEBUG -DOVR_BUILD_DEBUG -g $(DEFINES)
    RELEASETYPE   ?= Debug
    LFLAGS         = 
else
    CXXFLAGS      += $(COMMONFLAGS) -O2 $(DEFINES)
    RELEASETYPE   ?= Release
    LFLAGS         = -O1  # Why O1?
endif

####### Paths

OCULUSWORLDPATH = .
LIBOVRPATH      = ../../LibOVR
COMMONSRCPATH   = ../CommonSrc
3RDPARTYPATH    = ../../3rdParty
INCPATH         = -I. -I.. -I$(COMMONSRCPATH) -I$(LIBOVRPATH)/Include -I$(LIBOVRPATH)/Src
OBJPATH         = ./Obj/Linux/$(RELEASETYPE)/$(SYSARCH)
CXX_BUILD       = $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o $(OBJPATH)/

####### Files

LIBS          = -L$(LIBOVRPATH)/Lib/Linux/$(RELEASETYPE)/$(SYSARCH) \
        -lovr \
        -ludev \
        -lpthread \
        -lGL \
        -lX11 \
        -lXrandr \
        -lrt

TARGET        = ./Release/OculusWorldDemo_$(SYSARCH)_$(RELEASETYPE)

####### Rules

all:    $(TARGET)

OCULUSWORLD_SOURCE =    $(OCULUSWORLDPATH)/OculusWorldDemo.cpp \
                        $(OCULUSWORLDPATH)/OculusWorldDemo_Scene.cpp \
                        $(OCULUSWORLDPATH)/Player.cpp \
                        $(OCULUSWORLDPATH)/../CommonSrc/Util/RenderProfiler.cpp \
                        $(OCULUSWORLDPATH)/../CommonSrc/Util/OptionMenu.cpp \
                        $(OCULUSWORLDPATH)/../CommonSrc/Platform/Linux_Gamepad.cpp \
                        $(OCULUSWORLDPATH)/../CommonSrc/Platform/Linux_Platform.cpp \
                        $(OCULUSWORLDPATH)/../CommonSrc/Platform/Platform.cpp \
                        $(OCULUSWORLDPATH)/../CommonSrc/Render/Render_Device.cpp \
                        $(OCULUSWORLDPATH)/../CommonSrc/Render/Render_GL_Device.cpp \
                        $(OCULUSWORLDPATH)/../CommonSrc/Render/Render_LoadTextureDDS.cpp \
                        $(OCULUSWORLDPATH)/../CommonSrc/Render/Render_LoadTextureTGA.cpp \
                        $(OCULUSWORLDPATH)/../CommonSrc/Render/Render_XmlSceneLoader.cpp \
                        $(OCULUSWORLDPATH)/../../3rdParty/TinyXml/tinyxml2.cpp

OCULUSWORLD_OBJECTS = $(patsubst $(OCULUSWORLDPATH)%.cpp,$(OBJPATH)%.o,$(OCULUSWORLD_SOURCE))

OBJECTS = $(OTHER_OBJECTS) $(OCULUSWORLD_OBJECTS)

$(OBJPATH)/%.o: %.cpp
    -mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o $@ $<

$(LIBOVRPATH)/Lib/Linux/$(RELEASETYPE)/$(SYSARCH)/libovr.a:
    $(MAKE) -C $(LIBOVRPATH) DEBUG=$(DEBUG)

lib: $(LIBOVRPATH)/Lib/Linux/$(RELEASETYPE)/$(SYSARCH)/libovr.a

run: $(TARGET)
    $(TARGET)

$(TARGET):  $(OBJECTS) lib
    -mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(LINK) $(LFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS)

clean:
    -$(DELETEFILE) $(OBJECTS)
    -$(DELETEFILE) $(TARGET)

cleanall:
    -$(DELETEFILE) $(OBJECTS)
    -$(DELETEDIR) ./Release/*
```

---

```
xxx:~/Desktop/ing$ make
true
make -C ./LibOVR
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/bosch3d/Desktop/ing/LibOVR'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/bosch3d/Desktop/ing/LibOVR'
make -C ./Samples/OculusWorldDemo
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/bosch3d/Desktop/ing/Samples/OculusWorldDemo'
mkdir -p Release/
g++ -O1   -o ./Release/OculusWorldDemo_x86_64_Release  ./Obj/Linux/Release/x86_64/OculusWorldDemo.o ./Obj/Linux/Release/x86_64/OculusWorldDemo_Scene.o ./Obj/Linux/Release/x86_64/Player.o ./Obj/Linux/Release/x86_64/../CommonSrc/Util/RenderProfiler.o ./Obj/Linux/Release/x86_64/../CommonSrc/Util/OptionMenu.o ./Obj/Linux/Release/x86_64/../CommonSrc/Platform/Linux_Gamepad.o ./Obj/Linux/Release/x86_64/../CommonSrc/Platform/Linux_Platform.o ./Obj/Linux/Release/x86_64/../CommonSrc/Platform/Platform.o ./Obj/Linux/Release/x86_64/../CommonSrc/Render/Render_Device.o ./Obj/Linux/Release/x86_64/../CommonSrc/Render/Render_GL_Device.o ./Obj/Linux/Release/x86_64/../CommonSrc/Render/Render_LoadTextureDDS.o ./Obj/Linux/Release/x86_64/../CommonSrc/Render/Render_LoadTextureTGA.o ./Obj/Linux/Release/x86_64/../CommonSrc/Render/Render_XmlSceneLoader.o ./Obj/Linux/Release/x86_64/../../3rdParty/TinyXml/tinyxml2.o -L../../LibOVR/Lib/Linux/Release/x86_64 -lovr -ludev -lpthread -lGL -lX11 -lXrandr -lrt
./Obj/Linux/Release/x86_64/OculusWorldDemo.o: In function `OculusWorldDemoApp::~OculusWorldDemoApp()':
OculusWorldDemo.cpp:(.text+0x756): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
OculusWorldDemo.cpp:(.text+0x7d6): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
OculusWorldDemo.cpp:(.text+0x836): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
OculusWorldDemo.cpp:(.text+0x843): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
./Obj/Linux/Release/x86_64/OculusWorldDemo.o: In function `OculusWorldDemoApp::RenderEyeView(ovrEyeType)':
OculusWorldDemo.cpp:(.text+0x9064): undefined reference to `ReadDataRunML::run(bool)'
./Obj/Linux/Release/x86_64/OculusWorldDemo.o: In function `cv::Mat::~Mat()':
OculusWorldDemo.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3MatD2Ev[_ZN2cv3MatD5Ev]+0x89): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
OculusWorldDemo.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3MatD2Ev[_ZN2cv3MatD5Ev]+0x79): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
./Obj/Linux/Release/x86_64/OculusWorldDemo.o: In function `ReadDataRunML::~ReadDataRunML()':
OculusWorldDemo.cpp:(.text._ZN13ReadDataRunMLD2Ev[_ZN13ReadDataRunMLD5Ev]+0xa6): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
OculusWorldDemo.cpp:(.text._ZN13ReadDataRunMLD2Ev[_ZN13ReadDataRunMLD5Ev]+0x120): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
OculusWorldDemo.cpp:(.text._ZN13ReadDataRunMLD2Ev[_ZN13ReadDataRunMLD5Ev]+0x144): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
OculusWorldDemo.cpp:(.text._ZN13ReadDataRunMLD2Ev[_ZN13ReadDataRunMLD5Ev]+0x154): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
./Obj/Linux/Release/x86_64/OculusWorldDemo.o: In function `ReadDataRunML::ReadDataRunML(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int, double, int, int)':
OculusWorldDemo.cpp:(.text._ZN13ReadDataRunMLC2ESsidii[_ZN13ReadDataRunMLC5ESsidii]+0x1a3): undefined reference to `cv::String::allocate(unsigned long)'
OculusWorldDemo.cpp:(.text._ZN13ReadDataRunMLC2ESsidii[_ZN13ReadDataRunMLC5ESsidii]+0x1eb): undefined reference to `cv::ml::TrainData::loadFromCSV(cv::String const&, int, int, int, cv::String const&, char, char)'
OculusWorldDemo.cpp:(.text._ZN13ReadDataRunMLC2ESsidii[_ZN13ReadDataRunMLC5ESsidii]+0x1f8): undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
OculusWorldDemo.cpp:(.text._ZN13ReadDataRunMLC2ESsidii[_ZN13ReadDataRunMLC5ESsidii]+0x20b): undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
OculusWorldDemo.cpp:(.text._ZN13ReadDataRunMLC2ESsidii[_ZN13ReadDataRunMLC5ESsidii]+0x2ec): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
OculusWorldDemo.cpp:(.text._ZN13ReadDataRunMLC2ESsidii[_ZN13ReadDataRunMLC5ESsidii]+0x3db): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::copySize(cv::Mat const&)'
OculusWorldDemo.cpp:(.text._ZN13ReadDataRunMLC2ESsidii[_ZN13ReadDataRunMLC5ESsidii]+0x4c7): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
OculusWorldDemo.cpp:(.text._ZN13ReadDataRunMLC2ESsidii[_ZN13ReadDataRunMLC5ESsidii]+0x5bf): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::copySize(cv::Mat const&)'
OculusWorldDemo.cpp:(.text._ZN13ReadDataRunMLC2ESsidii[_ZN13ReadDataRunMLC5ESsidii]+0x6b8): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
OculusWorldDemo.cpp:(.text._ZN13ReadDataRunMLC2ESsidii[_ZN13ReadDataRunMLC5ESsidii]+0x6c7): undefined reference to `cv::Formatter::get(int)'
OculusWorldDemo.cpp:(.text._ZN13ReadDataRunMLC2ESsidii[_ZN13ReadDataRunMLC5ESsidii]+0x7c1): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
OculusWorldDemo.cpp:(.text._ZN13ReadDataRunMLC2ESsidii[_ZN13ReadDataRunMLC5ESsidii]+0x861): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
OculusWorldDemo.cpp:(.text._ZN13ReadDataRunMLC2ESsidii[_ZN13ReadDataRunMLC5ESsidii]+0x86e): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
OculusWorldDemo.cpp:(.text._ZN13ReadDataRunMLC2ESsidii[_ZN13ReadDataRunMLC5ESsidii]+0x882): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
OculusWorldDemo.cpp:(.text._ZN13ReadDataRunMLC2ESsidii[_ZN13ReadDataRunMLC5ESsidii]+0x88f): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
OculusWorldDemo.cpp:(.text._ZN13ReadDataRunMLC2ESsidii[_ZN13ReadDataRunMLC5ESsidii]+0x929): undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
OculusWorldDemo.cpp:(.text._ZN13ReadDataRunMLC2ESsidii[_ZN13ReadDataRunMLC5ESsidii]+0x975): undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Release/OculusWorldDemo_x86_64_Release] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/bosch3d/Desktop/ing/Samples/OculusWorldDemo'
make: *** [Samples/OculusWorldDemo/Release/OculusWorldDemo_x86_64_Release] Error 2
xxx:~/Desktop/ing$
```

I have added:

```
-lopencv_core \
-lopencv_highgui \
-lopencv_imgproc \
-lopencv_video \
-lopencv_objdetect \
```

Now the Errors are:

```
./Obj/Linux/Release/x86_64/OculusWorldDemo.o: In function `OculusWorldDemoApp::RenderEyeView(ovrEyeType)':
OculusWorldDemo.cpp:(.text+0x9064): undefined reference to `ReadDataRunML::run(bool)'
./Obj/Linux/Release/x86_64/OculusWorldDemo.o: In function `ReadDataRunML::ReadDataRunML(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int, double, int, int)':
OculusWorldDemo.cpp:(.text._ZN13ReadDataRunMLC2ESsidii[_ZN13ReadDataRunMLC5ESsidii]+0x1eb): undefined reference to `cv::ml::TrainData::loadFromCSV(cv::String const&, int, int, int, cv::String const&, char, char)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Release/OculusWorldDemo_x86_64_Release] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/bosch3d/Desktop/ing/Samples/OculusWorldDemo'
make: *** [Samples/OculusWorldDemo/Release/OculusWorldDemo_x86_64_Release] Error 2
```

ReadDataRunML is a class added by myself. How should I add it to MakeFile?

Comment: Smells like `$LIBS` is incorrect.

Comment: I have just tried delete `$(LIBS)`. Doesn't work either...@Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams

Comment: You wouldn't delete it. You'd add the correct entries to it.

Comment: edited my question. Thank you!@Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `opencv` libraries to the list of libs you link with:

Add to the LIBS section of your MakeFile:

```
-lopencv_core \
```

and, depending on which opencv features you use, you may need one or more of the following:

```
-lopencv_highgui \
-lopencv_imgproc \
-lopencv_video \
-lopencv_objdetect \
```

The unresolved externals are simply because the linker doesn't know where to look for them.  Also, make sure your opencv library path is either in your lib path or add it to the libpath used by the linker.  You can add to the library path with the `-L` option, e.g. `-LMyLocalPathToOpenCV` (rather than hard-coding it where you add it to the linker options, you'll probably want define it and use a macro to refer to it, to keep your makefile cleaner, e.g. `$(OPENCV_LIB_PATH)`).